# Why did the French SFIO abandon its anti-militaristic views after Jaures' death?

Tags: world-war-one, france, communism

Before his murder on July 31st 1914, Jaures and the SFIO attempted to unite the workers of the different European countries to not take part in what became WWI. However, only two days after his death, SFIO leaders backed the war entirely. I wasn't able to find an answer to that sudden change.

Comment: The most obvious answer would seem to be that the anti-militaristic views mainly belonged to Jaures, and his death allowed the rest of the leadership to follow their own path.

Comment: Surely Jaures must have had a lot of weight in the decisions made by the party but it says here that the SFIO published an anti-war manifest on July 28th 1914 (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_fran%C3%A7aise_de_l%27Internationale_ouvri%C3%A8re#:~:text=Le%2028%20juillet%201914%2C%20la%20SFIO%20publie%20un%20manifeste%20disant%20%C2%AB%C2%A0%C3%80%20bas%20la%20guerre%C2%A0!%20Vive%20la%20r%C3%A9publique%20sociale%C2%A0!%20Vive%20le%20socialisme%20international%C2%A0!%C2%A0%C2%BB)

Comment: Another explanation can be what happened in the meantime:
1st Aug: France mobilise the army, 3rd Aug: Germany declaration of war. So, on 3rd of Aug, France was in war, and that change a lot

Comment: From [French Section of the Workers' International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Section_of_the_Workers%27_International) "During the July 1914 international crisis, the party was ideologically torn between its membership in the Socialist International and the wave of patriotism within France. The assassination of Jaurès on 31 July 1914 was a setback for the pacifist wing of the party and contributed to the massive increase in support for the wartime government of national unity."

Comment: Also, [French wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_fran%C3%A7aise_de_l%27Internationale_ouvri%C3%A8re) states "Dès le 2 août, il y a un basculement total avec le discours de Vaillant qui déclare « **en présence de l'agression**, les socialistes accompliront tous leur devoir pour la patrie ». If this and the info in my previous comment don't answer your question, please edit to clarify what you think is missing. Thank you.

Comment: @LarsBosteen But the 'agression' only took place the following day according to the previous comment.

Comment: @user1627466 - but everyone could see what was unfolding - there was no stopping it by then.

Comment: Have a look at [Timeline of World War I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_World_War_I#1914). Germany declared war on Russia (France's ally) on the 1st and invaded Luxembourg (France's neighbour) on the 2nd. Aggressive intent affecting French interests was clear.

Comment: @JonCuster But surely the situation was also clear on the 28th when the SFIO was still officially anti-war. What I also cannot fathom is why they would join the war when Jaures was killed by a  pro-war nationalist.

Comment: @user1627466 - mobilization had not started. Once it did, there was no going back and everyone knew it.